# MySQL how to select the entire row for the max(salary)

Tags: mysql, sql

[enter image description here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxr4B.png)

Comment: Please describe your error correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a table name employees that table have a column name =income and you want to find max salary from the table and your query will be

```
SELECT MAX(income) AS "Maximum Income" FROM employees;
```